# Formula for summation on amount of equal column values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given a spreadsheet with two columns, say A and B, each containing n values under it, all text; is there a formula that allows me to fill just one cell containing the amount of equal values in columns A and B?

Example:

```
    A   B
    -----
1   M   M
2   L   M
3   L   L
4   M   M
5   M   L
    -----
        3
```

Since columns A and B both contain an `M` in rows 1 and 4, and an `L` in row 3, the result is (i.e. 2+1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use ***QUERY*** function in google spreadsheet:

```
=SUM(QUERY(A1:B5, "Select 1 where A = B"))
```

Or using ***SUMPRODUCT***:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(((A:A)=(B:B)) * (1) ))
```

Comment: What do you know; they both work. I've never seen the SUM work with the ARRAYFORMULA. (Had to make sheets, so dug in deep the past week)
Thanks for them. I'll check it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution will be to add the following formula in column C: `=N(EXACT(A1,B1))`,
copy it throughout the column down to the last row and then sum up the column C values using `=SUM(C1:C5)`.

Comment: Nice idea, though I don't want to use an extra column, since it would require me to add about 100 extra columns manually. I really need the one formula I can copy paste in an entire row that will do this trick. =)

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

```
 =IF(EQ(LEFT(A0, 1), "A"),
     SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(N(EXACT(TRANSPOSE(A1:A5), TRANSPOSE(B1:B5))))),
     "")
```

Reading: if the value in row 0 (it doesn't exist, but my example above does ;) ) is equal to the text "A", take the sum of an array N, otherwise put in an empty string. ("")

Array N is build by taking the transpose of columns A and B. (Turning them, so they look like a row) and comparing the values. (Burnash gave me the options "N" and "EXACT") The formula N transforms this into a 1 or 0.

Copy paste the formula in an entire row and what do you know... It worked! That was hellish for something so trivial.

Thanks anyway.