# Automating Chart Data generation for a Daily Expenses per Tag

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets, google-docs

Using Google Spreadsheets. Here's an attempt to replicate my table needs:

```
2012-08-30    food     $15    expensive dinner
2012-08-30    food     $10    pizza!
2012-08-30    other    $30    that damn painting
2012-09-02    home     $40    can't remember
2012-09-02    other    $5     toilet paper
2012-09-02    home     $2     buying new flowers
```

I can already do 2 things with it, but it is so far from optimal it becomes negligible.

First, [Using `SUMIF`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18277/sum-of-all-cells-in-google-spreadsheet-where-matching-row-fits-a-value):

```
food    $25    <-    SUMIF(B:B;"food";C:C)
other   $35
home    $42
```

Then, combining it [with `ARRAYFORMULA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9128987/sumifs-function-in-google-spreadsheet):

```
           food home other
2012-08-30  $25   $0   $30 <- ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A:A&B:B;2012-08-30&"food";C:C))
2012-09-02   $0  $42    $5
```

See where this can become too big? Well...

I want to do 2 graphic charts out of this. Of course, the main one is the second:

1. *A pie*, from the first example. On using the `SUMIF`, I need to explicitly, write `"food"` there (or reference, whatever). Could that be done automagically filling every **tag** found?

   While I can live without this, it may be the answer to the second, main question;
2. *A plot* or *timeline*, from the *arrayformula*. It should trace each tag in a plot along the time.

Is it even possible to be done? If not, any suggestions? I'm keen to [start scripting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/your_first_script) if needed (and worth it). Or move away from google. Or from spreadsheets all together (lastly). Python maybe? Ruby?

Or maybe I'll just leave it as it is, if it's tooooo much trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using QUERY, you can generate the first table (with headers) using:

```
=QUERY(B:C;"select B, sum(C) where B != '' group by B label B 'Category', sum(C) 'Total'";0)
```

and this should be fairly easily plotted as a pie chart. You can select a range for the chart that is much longer than the current table to accommodate growing data, and the pie chart will conveniently ignore blank rows.

The second table can be generated using:

```
=QUERY(A:C;"select A, sum(C) where A is not null group by A pivot B";0)
```

and you can experiment with various chart types to achieve the desired visualisation.

---

edit

To provide a table that populates with zeros instead of blanks as per your comment; assuming the upper left (blank) cell of the table is `I1`, then in `I2`:

```
=SORT(UNIQUE(A:A))
```

and in `J1`:

```
=TRANSPOSE(SORT(UNIQUE(B:B)))
```

and then in `J2`:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(I2:I*LEN(J1:1);MMULT(I2:I=TRANSPOSE(A:A);(J1:1=B:B)*C:C);IFERROR(1/0)))
```

Note this will populate `CONTINUE` functions to the far bottom and far right of the spreadsheet, over-writing everything in their path. So probably best to have a sheet dedicated to this table.

Comment: I've tweaked the formulas a little, and I intent to present final result, but I still got 2 minor issues I wish to fix here: (1) the graphs aren't auto updating with your provided formulas (which work great) so if I add a new tag (or category) the graph won't pick up unless I pre-buff the sheets with a certain amount of rows and cols; and (2) I spent a couple hours trying to look how to fill in the second table with ZEROs (instead of empty spaces) but couldn't find out. without this, the graph looks weirder. would you happen to have fixes for those too?

Comment: 1. Yes, you will need to specify ranges that extend beyond what you predict to be filled. Or otherwise, use GAS to adjust the data range sizes "on edit". But the first way would be easier to implement IMO and perhaps give better performance in the long run.

Comment: 2. This is a bit of a limitation with QUERY. There would be convoluted workarounds with QUERY, but I will edit my answer to provide another way.

Answer (score 1):

In general, Spreadsheets are not Databases, and this is a task for which you are fast approaching needing a database.  However, as luck would have it (depending on how you look at it, anyhow), Google Spreadsheets actually *do* have some database-like access APIs, so you can probably do what you want:

http://googleajaxsearchapi.blogspot.com/2008/03/introducing-latest-ajax-api-google.html

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage

http://blog.ouseful.info/2009/05/18/using-google-spreadsheets-as-a-databace-with-the-google-visualisation-api-query-language/

Comment: Coincidentally [I've just stumbled upon *queries*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9087667/spreadsheet-formula-for-summation-on-amount-of-equal-column-values) and I liked it... I love SQL. But I still don't see how those could help me building the datasets automatically for the charts to pick them up. As I see them right now, they're just another way to write a different syntax to get into same results from the formula already provided.

Comment: My question title was ill written. I hope it's clearer now. Meanwhile, that "developers interactive chart" might be my answer...

Comment: Well... Nope, nothing of this helped! Now I think I got my question right. :)